# SOUND WAVES :: organ pipes

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions, resonance

Why doesn't sound wave escape in a open end pipe, why does it reflect again at open end of organ pipe when it can just move outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question on open organ pipe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150929/)