# Why must there be an antinode at an open end?

Tags: waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions, resonance

[image]

Consider the above diagram.

I am currently learning about standing waves in an open and closed tube. To me, it is trivial why at a closed end, there must be a node, as particles are not free to move around back and forth. However, to me an open end is not so trivial. Why must it be an antinode rather than some other part in the wave?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150929/2451 and links therein.