# Why is there a pressure node at the open end?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, boundary-conditions, resonance

The pressure at the open end is equal to that of the atmospheric pressure. So how can it be a pressure node when the pressure is not 0? It is the atmospheric pressure.

**Edit:** Is there an intuitive reason for why the open end must be equal to atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150929/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When we are discussing the pressure in a pipe we are referring to the [gauge pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement#Absolute,_gauge_and_differential_pressures_%E2%80%94_zero_reference). This is the pressure in the pipe *minus* atmospheric pressure.

So when we refer to a *pressure node* we mean the gauge pressure is zero i.e. that the pressure at a node is equal to atmospheric pressure. And since, as you correctly say, the pressure at the end of the pipe is 1 atm that means the gauge pressure at the end of the pipe is zero and therefore that there is a node at the end of the pipe.

Comment: Great answer. I was also wondering if you could provide an explanation for why the pressure is exactly equal to the atmospheric pressure at the open end?

Comment: The pressure is not exactly zero at the end, often the node is slightly beyond the open end. If there is high pressure at a certain spot, the air will try to equalize by flowing to a lower pressure. At the closed end this is prevented by the wall of the instrument and so pressure is allowed to build up. At the open end there is nothing to prevent air from escaping so air can more easily equalize towards atmospheric pressure. This does not work perfectly, which is obvious by the fact that waves in air exist at all.

Comment: For more info see https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section3_6/Sec3_6.htm at end correction

Comment: @QuinGardinerBax The pressure at the end is actually slightly lower than atmospheric so in fact it isn't quite a node at the end. This lower pressure is what causes the wave to reflect back down into the pipe to create the standing wave. For more on this see [How can standing waves be produced in an open organ pipe if the ends are open?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150929/how-can-standing-waves-be-produced-in-an-open-organ-pipe-if-the-ends-are-open)